# iTunes installation failure

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-registry

I 'm trying to install iTunes setup (Microsoft Windows 7 64 bit) but installation fails with error (picture below).

Any ideas how can I fix it?

[image]

*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run -> Permissions -> Advanced icon:*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the install with elevation?

Comment: Logged in as an admin, right click the installer and "Run as Admin"

Comment: Start `regedit.exe`, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and try creating a new value manually.

Comment: @and31415 I navigated but I don't how to continue. Could you be more specific because I 'm a newbie.

Comment: @dempap Sure. Right-click an empty spot in the right pane, then choose **New > String Value**.

Comment: @and31415 I did this but what I have to edit to the `Value Data`? Thank's in advance.

Comment: @dempap No, there's no need. It was mostly a test to see whether you could create new registry values. Right-click the `Run` key in the left pane, and choose **Permission** from the menu. Then click **Advanced** and make a screenshot.

Comment: @and31415 I edited my question with the screenshot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14005/discussion-between-dempap-and-and31415)

Answer (score 0):

Try running iTunes setup as Administrator. To accomplish this, right-cilck on it executable and choose `Run As Administrator` from menu.